# How to set App title at center in Navigation drawer Action Bar?

Tags: android-actionbar

I want to customize navigation drawer app compact action bar, I want to remove app icon from that and want to make its title center in action bar.

I have applied all solutions , but nothing is working with all the conditions.

Please give me some clue for applying.

In Simple Activity we can create custom Action bar , but how to create customize navigation drawer action bar

Please Share your idea's .....

Answer (score 1):

To archive having a centered title in ABS (if you want to have this in the default ActionBar, just remove the "support" in the method names), you could just do this:

In your Activity, in your onCreate() method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
```

abs_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="my Title"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now you should have an Actionbar with just a title. If you want to set a custom background, set it in the Layout above (but then don't forget to set android:layout_height="match_parent").

or with:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage)
```

Answer (score 0):

a trick for this problem. 
use can custom a layout, which contains a text view to show the title like that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sfsdf"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

In your Activity, in your onCreate() method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
```

Here is result:
[image]